# Shortcode doesn't display in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

I created a custom post type, but when I add a shortcode for a slider, it doesn't show the slider it shows just the shortcode in text.

And, when I change `get_the_content` by `the_content`, it shows me just a little text like excerpt.

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <header class="singleheader">
        <div class="singlettlpart">
            <h1 class="singlettl"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php $post_id = get_the_ID();
            $hotel_data = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_hotel', true );
            $adr = ( empty( $hotel_data['adr'] ) ) ? 'Aucune adresse trouvée' : $hotel_data['adr'];
            echo $adr; ?> <a href="#carte" class="cartelnk">(voir la carte)</a>
        </div>
        <div class="prxpart">
            <h1 class="prxttl">À partir de <br />
                <?php 
                $prx = ( empty( $hotel_data['prx'] ) ) ? '???' : $hotel_data['prx'];
                echo $prx; ?> € / NUIT
            </h1>
        </div>
        </header><a id="pres"></a>
        <div class="singletxt">
            <?php 
                $content = get_the_content();
                echo $content; ?>
                <a id="pho"></a>
                <a id="chm"></a>
                <a id="cprx"></a>
        </div>
    <?php else :
    echo 'Pas de hotels pour l\'instant';
endif;?>
```

Comment: so you're saying using `the_content` doesn't render shortcodes? shortcodes not working with `get_the_content` is expected, as is noted in [the documentation for that function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content).

Comment: oh ok so with get_the_content i can't make shortcode work.
but when i use the_content it shows just a little of text like excerpt, i don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just

```
echo do_shortcode( $content );
```

[Function Reference/do shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)

Comment: hhhhhhhhh seriously i don't know with which ink did you write your answer but its work although i have tried this 2 times before i don't know why it doesn't work for me before.

Thank you.